# Access violation at tcriticalsection.create

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am programming a multi-threaded chat server application. Thus critical section are very necessary. I just made a wrapper class for threaded tree view. It works perfectly in the client but the server raises an AV.

There are two forms, FormServer (which practically does almost no processing except for gui painting) and the DataModuleServer which does all the heavy lifting.

The FormServer gets created first.

Actually the threaded tree view is inside another wrapper class TRoomTree.

**TDataModuleServer.Create**

```
procedure TDataModuleServer.cr(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Rooms := TRoomTree.Create (FormServer.tvRooms);
```

tvRooms : the visual treeview

**TRoomTree.Create**

```
constructor TRoomTree.Create (TV : TTreeView);
begin

  if Assigned (TV) then
    fTreeView.Create (TV)
  else
    exit;
```

fTreeView : the threaded tree view;

**TThreadTreeView.Create**

```
constructor TThreadTreeView.Create (TreeView : TTreeView = nil);
begin

  fLock := TCriticalSection.Create;

  if Assigned (TreeView) then
    fTreeView := TreeView
  else
    fTreeView := TTreeView.Create (nil);

end;
```

fTreeView : the normal tree view;

Now the TCriticalSection.Create raises an AV exception in ntdll.dll.

**Call Stack**

```
:76cac41f KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x58
:0040469c NotifyNonDelphiException + $1C
:77ecb42b ; ntdll.dll
uThreadTreeView.TThreadTreeView.Create($26B4300) 
uRoomTree.TRoomTree.Create($26B4300)
uServer.TDataModuleServer.cr($26A48B0)
Classes.TDataModule.DoCreate
Classes.TDataModule.AfterConstruction
System.@AfterConstruction($26A48B0)
Classes.TDataModule.Create(???)
Forms.TApplication.CreateForm(???,(no value))
PlayburnServer.PlayburnServer
:773833aa kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:77ea9ef2 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63
:77ea9ec5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VCL components should not be accessed by a worker thread. Better leave that to the main VCL thread and either use Synchronize or messages between VCL main thread and worker threads. This matter has been discussed before on SO.

Comment: Exiting from a constructor is problematic - what other initialization are you skipping?  I think it would be better to `Assert(Assigned(TV))` there, and I'd rather have it have an access violation or raise an exception than stop than continue with a half constructed object... wouldn't you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `TRoomTree.Create`, this line of code

```
fTreeView.Create(TV);
```

is responsible for your access violation. That's because `fTreeView` has not been initialised before you attempt to call a method on it.

Delphi instances are created like this:

```
fTreeView := TThreadTreeView.Create(TV);
```

I'm not sure about your threading model, but I trust you are aware that VCL controls must only be accessed from the GUI thread.

Comment: Hehe - the old 'uns are the best <g>.  'In fact, in XE3, the compiler has been changed to remove that capability'  AT LAST!  IT'S ONLY TAKEN 2 DECADES!

Comment: @MartinJames I still remember firing up Delphi 1 for the first time and making this exact same mistake. Happy days!

Comment: I think I was at D3 when I first asked for a warning for this.  I still make the same error now, but the immediate AV and lots of Delphi experience now makes it just an annoyance.

Comment: but copy constructor in delphi would not be necessarily bad thing // OTOH without copy contructor - any constructor should be class method by definition

Comment: Many a time I have made this error, usually it only takes a few seconds to realise the mistake but I have spent hours before not able to see what was wrong with the code.

Comment: @Arioch Delphi doesn't have copy constructors. That's C++. This *feature* is a hang-over from old style TP objects. It has no value since without it there are perfectly acceptable alternatives that achieve the same effect. It's great that it has been killed. It will mean an end to all these Stack Overflow questions. The main achievement of this feature has been to confuse developers who have fallen into the trap.

Comment: So does this mean `TApplication.CreateForm` has changed, too, @David? Besides constructor implementations (which call constructors on instances all the time), that's the main consumer of that feature that I can think of. It used to call `FormClass.NewInstance`, then assign the global variable, and then call `Instance.Create`. If calling constructors on instances isn't allowed anymore, then how does `CreateForm` work?

Comment: @RobKennedy Good point. And `CreateForm` is implemented exactly as it ever was. The XE3 change is odd. You can call `x.Create` when `x` is an instance variable, so long as `x` is not `Self`. So `Self.Create` or `Create` in an instance method are now compiler errors. That said you can do `obj := Self; obj.Create;`!!! I really can't explain this change out at all.

Comment: ...maybe they would finally introduce "procedure of self" type :-D just kidding. Or maybe not.

Comment: @David Thanks. I can't believe I missed it. Thanks again.